# Tensorflow Object-detection model training failed on google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

> ERROR 2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service     The replica worker 2 exited
> with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error.
>
> ERROR 2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service     Traceback (most recent call
> last):
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service       File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
> ERROR 2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service         "**main**", fname,
> loader, pkg_name)
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service       File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23
> 18:39:51 -0800    service         exec code in run_globals
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23
> 18:39:51 -0800    service       File
> "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
> line 49, in
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service         from
> object_detection import trainer
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51
> -0800 service       File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py",
> line 27, in
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service         from
> object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23
> 18:39:51 -0800    service       File
> "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py",
> line 21, in
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service         from
> object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23
> 18:39:51 -0800    service       File
> "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py",
> line 71, in
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800   service  options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
>
> ERROR  2017-11-23 18:39:51
> -0800 service     TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

Using `protobuf (3.5.0.post1)`

But when I run taining local, no error!

Comment: 2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800 service File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py", line 71, in ERROR 2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800 service options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR), ERROR 

2017-11-23 18:39:51 -0800 service TypeError: new() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

Comment: Could you provide some of the code in trainer.py?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/trainer.py

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud ML Engine doesn't support the latest versions of TensorFlow or protobuf. You can see the current packages and versions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list). Did you add protobuf to the list of required packages in setup.py?

In setup.py, you can request a more current version of TensorFlow with code like the following:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow>=1.3']
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    ...
)
```

Comment: I downgrade to tensorflow 1.2. but got another error. File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 24, in <module>,import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: Right. You can't access matplotlib when you deploy code to the ML Engine.